# Parent docker container does not stop and I need to access terminal and run my commands

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile

I have a dockerfile (lets say `image2`) which starts `image1` as follows

```
FROM custom-container:version
```

The above `image1` has an entry point which starts a java server which I need. The terminal does not stop as the java process doesnt exit.

However I need to execute commands in my container on `image2`. How can I achieve that

```
docker run -ti image2
```

The above starts the java server in `image1` as expected but after that I also need access to the terminal of `image2`'s container. What is the way to go about doing this?

Comment: open up another terminal: docker exec -it image2 bin/bash

Comment: @RutgerVk that worked if I do `docker exec -ti running-container-id /bin/bash`.  Now however the image2's entrypoint script is never executed as the java server has not stopped. Is there a way I can do the same such that I can just run "image2" and get this new terminal opened without using exec

Comment: I'm sorry I donnot know, I dive into it after work if you havent had a response yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the container from image2 in background:

```
docker run -d --name app image2
```

Get a shell into the container and run commands

```
docker exec -it app bash
```